# Building a notification from a modal in React Navigation

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am attempting to build a notification service I can use within React Navigation; how far I have gotten in this:

[image]

Now this is a modal, that the card element has been hidden and then the view style has been filled into only 15% at the top of the element, and the element will react if you click out of the white area of the notification.

Here is the code for the NotificationModal:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableHighlight,TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class NotificationModal extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const title = navigation.getParam('title','No item found...');
        return {
            title: title
        };
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        let title = navigation.getParam('title', '');
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 ,flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
                    <View style={{ height: "15%" ,width: '100%', backgroundColor:"#fff", justifyContent:"center"}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:25}}>{title}xd</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.goBack(); }} style={{backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"}}>
                        <View style={{ height: "85%" ,width: '100%', backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", justifyContent:"center"}}>
                            <View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
}
```

At at my root navigation stack it looks like this:

```
export default RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: MainStack,
        },
        QuickStockModal: {
            screen: StockModal,
        },
        NotificationModal: {
            screen: NotificationModal,
        }
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'none',
        cardStyle:{
            backgroundColor:"transparent",
            opacity:0.99
        }
    }
);
```

Finally I call this pseudo notification modal like any other navigation instance:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('NotificationModal', {
            title: 'test'
        });
```

**Problems with this**

1. It wont just act as a quick update, it will overtake the touch area, I just wish to let the user know things like 'search results empty' or 'barcode invalid' etc, without hijacking the touch. (But being able to touch buttons of the notification within the white area thats visible)
2. When you press the outside area to dismiss it, the 'dismiss area' turns dark as it disappears, this looks bad, I am hoping to change the animation to simply push up instead of down and hopefully avoid this
3. this is a messy way to do notifications but other manners will complicate my current app design too much (Using Redux for instance, will be alot of work for simply trying to add in-app notifications)
4. In-app notification libs arent customizable enough and also dont even work properly sadly

Comment: Use a `<View>` with absolute positioning instead of `Modal`. Maybe you can show a 'X' icon on the notification to dismiss it. You cannot make it dismiss when outside area is touched without hijacking touch because touch events are not passed through in React Native. You may be able to solve the touch issue with `PanResponder` though - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder

Comment: Problem is, rendering over react navigation needs a modal, I cant just call a view alone

Comment: If you use redux, you can render the View outside of your Navigator and show/hide based on a state value. I have done this and it works.

Comment: Yeah im afraid Redux seems to be the only way to manage this sort of use case, but I was hoping to avoid it if possible in favor of something more native to the libraries I have installed. Seems its going to be my quickest and best option regardless though